# Datetime in For loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a for loop in date time how ever `counter` doesn't increase. I didn't see the reason. Can you help me on it?

```
private void ubGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime startDate = udteMin.DateTime.Date;
    DateTime endDate = udteMax.DateTime.Date;

    for (DateTime counter = startDate; counter <= endDate; counter.AddDays(1))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(counter.Date.ToString() + "            " + counter.AddDays(1).Date.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AddDays` returns a new DateTime object. It doesn't mutate your existing one. You'll need to reassign counter with the result of AddDays

```
counter = counter.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there have been a warning for that in the IDE?

Comment: Yeah depending on your IDE and settings you can get a warning that you're throwing away the result of the method call